# Доступ к переменной из двух потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность, структуры-данных

У меня есть следующая задача: код должен складывать куда-то значения переменной (от 1 до 5) в двух параллельных несинхронизированных потоках. Если один из потоков положил число 5 - он выводится на печать и оба потока завершаются. Какую структуру данных использовать и как узнать, какой поток завершился первым, чтобы вывести его?

Comment: Можно использовать `volatile int` или `AtomicInteger` из пакета `java.util.concurrent.atomic` для хранения переменной.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то для этого существует слово `volatile`. Оно означает, что поле может меняться из двух потоков.

Comment: Какую структуру данных использовать и как узнать, какой поток завершился первым, чтобы вывести его? - кого его? цифру 5 вывели, что еще вы хотите вывести "первым"? кроме того, напишите код с желаемой логикой в двух потоках и добавьте его. с этим , судя по описанию задачи проблем нет. а уже к этому коду можно будет и решение докручивать

Answer (score 0):

Если случайно выбрасывать в интервале 1..5, то первый поток успевает всё сделать ещё до того, как второй начнёт. Вот если выбрасывать в интервале 1..5000, то тогда шансы и второго появляются

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var LUCKY_NUMBER = 5;
        var MAX_NUMBER = 5000;
        var value = new AtomicInteger();
        var rnd = new Random();
        var luckyThread = new AtomicReference();
        var runnable = (Runnable) () -> {
            while (true) {
                var new_v = rnd.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER)+1;
                var old_v = value.getAndSet(new_v);
                if (new_v == LUCKY_NUMBER && old_v != LUCKY_NUMBER) {
                    luckyThread.set(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    break;
                } else if (old_v == LUCKY_NUMBER) {
                    break;
                }
            }    
        };
        var t1 = new Thread(runnable);
        var t2 = new Thread(runnable);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("Lucky thread is "+ luckyThread.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance."

Comment: Ага, мне пришлось с 5 до 5000 увеличить интервал, чтобы чуть-чуть это всё замедлить, только быстрого генератора тут не хватало. :)